# Unable to add mysql into #include

Tags: c++, xcode, mysql-connector

I am trying to set up a simple test connection to a SQL server to eventually pull information out of the server

I can't seem to find any information on how to point to these on the device

I have installed homebrew, Boot and the mysql-connector-c++

```cpp
#include <mysql_connection.h>
```

mysql_connection.h file not found

OS: Mac​ OS 10.14.6 xcode: Version 11.0

Comment: You may need a `-I<path to sql include folder>` on the command line to give the compiler a hint.

Comment: Do you mean something like `#include -I<usr/local/opt/mysql-client/include/mysql_connection.h>`?

Comment: Sort of. `-Iusr/local/opt/mysql-client/include` goes on the compiler command line. If you are using an IDE, there will be a property page you'll need to edit.

Comment: @user4581301 would you know where I might find this in the Xcode

Comment: I don't know XCode worth beans I'm afraid, but a websearch for *xcode header search path* might get you looking in the right place.